# Error on SQL tools

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools

I am not sure what is the problem here. I tried to know better about this exception but all the details refer to the C# programming.

> ------ Build started: Project: ReportV, Configuration: Debug ------ Skipping 'DataSourceV.rds'. Item is up to date. Skipping
>   'DataSetV.rsd'. Item is up to date. Skipping 'Report1.rdl'. Item is up
>   to date. Fin de la génération -- 0 errors, 0 warnings
>   ========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ========== System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException: The communication object,
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel, cannot
>   be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.ThrowIfDisposedOrNotOpen()
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.OutputChannel.BeginSend(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DuplexChannelBinder.BeginRequest(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.StartSend(Boolean
>   completedSynchronously)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.FinishEnsureOpen(IAsyncResult
>   result, Boolean completedSynchronously)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.StartEnsureOpen(Boolean
>   completedSynchronously)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.FinishEnsureInteractiveInit(IAsyncResult
>   result, Boolean completedSynchronously)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.StartEnsureInteractiveInit()
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.Begin()
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.BeginCall(String
>   action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object asyncState)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeBeginService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Design.IPreviewProcessing.BeginSetItemPath(String
>   itemPath, AsyncCallback callback, Object asyncState)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Design.PreviewProcessingClient.BeginSetItemPath(String
>   itemPath, AsyncCallback callback, Object asyncState)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Design.WCFProcessingHost.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(AsyncCallback
>   ac, Object s)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Design.WCFProcessingHost.<>c__DisplayClass3b.b__39()
>   at
>   Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Design.WCFProcessingHost.ExecuteWcfCall(Action
>   wcfCall)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Design.WCFProcessingHost.ExecuteAsyncCall(Func`3
>   beginAction, AsyncCallback endAction)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Design.WCFProcessingHost.set_ItemContext(PreviewItemContext
>   value)    at
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.ChangeReportDefinition(DefinitionSource
>   updatingSourceType, Action changeAction)    at
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.set_ReportPath(String value) 
>   at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Design.PreviewFrame.RefreshPreview()

[image]

Comment: That error isn't in English, and as an image. SO is a English site, so please post questions and messages in English; or at least via Google Translate. Thanks. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: please provide the exception as text format and please translate to english.

Comment: I get I know understand what the problem is, you software trying to reach a web service (it says something like SOAP incorrect) and it does not exist or incorrect url, the question is why that happen? you need to know about your software.

Comment: Without code it's anyones guess. Do you know which line this occurs on? If not you should learn to debug

Answer (score 0):

This error message is related with the duplex WCF service.
The client can not consummate WCF due to the problem in WCF or connection between server and client.

Give as the code where stack trace is shown.